# Not getting into the callback when calling my jquery plugin

Tags: jquery

I created a jquery plugin which inserts the element `#tweetFeed`, along with some other things. When I call my plugin, and then try to insert an element into `#tweetFeed` in the callback, it doesn't insert it. Any ideas why?

Here's the code that is calling the plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // add the sidebar plugin
    $('html').social(function() {

        //doesn't print anything...ARGGG!!
        console.log('#tweetFeed = '+ $('#tweetFeed').parent().html());
        //$('#tweetFeed').append("<p>TEST</p>");
        //alert("test alert");  // this works now!

        //this line does NOT work. Why?
        $('#tweetFeed').append('<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script><script>new TWTR.Widget({version: 2,type: \'profile\',rpp: 4,interval: 6000,width: 250,height: 280,theme: {shell: {background: \'#333333\',color: \'#ffffff\'},tweets: {background: \'#ffffff\',color: \'#444444\',links: \'#e02046\'}},features: {scrollbar: false,loop: false,live: false,hashtags: true,timestamp: true,avatars: false,behavior: \'all\'}}).render().setUser(\'CSuitesIndepend\').start();</script>'); 
    }); 

});
```

You can see a live example of my problem [here](http://social.allthingswebdesign.com)

**EDIT:** After adding @Nicos suggestion, my plugin looks like this:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.social = function(callback) {

        var defaults = {

        };
        var options = null;
        var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options); 

        // stuff goes on here


        if(typeof callback == 'function'){
            callback.call(this);
        }
        return this;
    }
})(jQuery)
```

The only problem is when I try to append my twitter js code, I get errors which you can see [here](http://social.allthingswebdesign.com) . What is causing these errors? The alert works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look, the declaration of your plugin must recieve the function that you want do recieve...

Please, remove that code on the end of your plugin. Change your plugin to the latest version before you made that changes.

after that you must change this 2 lines:

1. `$.fn.social = function() {`
2. `return this;`

the first one will look like this:

`$.fn.social = function(callback) {`

and the second one will be looking lke this:

```
if(typeof callback == 'function'){
  callback.call(this, data);
}
return this;
```

this last bit of code ensures that your plugin will call tha callback function, if you don`t do that the callback is never called

if you want the code already changed look [here](http://pastebin.com/ervsDxPk)

P.S. i will delete this paste to protect your plugin, just warn me when you read it

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the plugin, but I think the problem is probably with `insertAfter`.  This takes the element in the selection, then inserts it after the element specified by the argument (in this case `"<p>TEST</p>"`).  Obviously, since that isn't attached to the document, you see no effect. (In fact, `#tweetfeed` will be removed from the original document.)

You should use [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append) instead.  This takes the content in the argument and appends it to the element selected.  This is what you intend, I think.

```
$('#tweetFeed').append("<p>TEST</p>");
```

Comment: In either case, it's not getting into the callback to even print the console.log.

Answer (score 0):

in the declaration of your plugin you should write something like that:

```
$.extend({
  myFunc : function(someArg, callbackFnk){
    // do something here
    var data = 'test';

    // now call a callback function
    if(typeof callbackFnk == 'function'){
      callbackFnk.call(this, data);
    }
  }
});
```

and then you can call like that:

```
$('#elementId').myFunc(someArg, function(arg){
  // now my function is not hardcoded
  // in the plugin itself
  // and arg = 'test'
});
```

to see more of it check this [link](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/11/create-callback-functions-for-your.html)

**EDIT**

The way you create your plugin you cant use that function as a callback, you never call that.
just add this and it will work

Comment: I've added your code to the end of my plugin, but i'm not sure if I've added it in the correct spot. It's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something in your code, it doesn't look like $().social() takes a function as an argument, nor does it fire off a callback, which would explain why nothing is happening. I really suggest reading these two articles about common jquery patterns:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/a-plugin-development-pattern